# Magento CE 2.3.4 - strict mime-type checking

Tags: magento2.3.4

To whom it may concern:
I installed and run magento CE 2.3.4 on windows 10 pro with wamp. Neither backend nor frontend works properly. Browser console gives the message: Strict Mimetype checking enabled and on account of that too many js files are not loaded in related page. I gather this could be resolved from .htaccess, yet this is Magento , a remarkable content management system, why is it happened at the first place? and what the fixes could be?

Answer (score 0):

The work around is in the file **validator.php** located @:

> {Magento_Dir}\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

line 138:

```
//$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

I found the answer in magento forum itself.